# Removing \r\n from JSON strings within quotes to get multiple lines

Tags: python, json, newline

I have a large text file that contains multiple sequential JSON objects. As far as I can tell, the best way to individual interpret/load the JSON objects would be to take them from the text file and put them on separate lines so that I can iterate through them line by line.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get python to separate them onto individual lines without the JSON structure being ruined to the point of illegibility. Also, these files are pretty big, and they have a lot of information. Please let me know the best way to either a) get the different JSON object strings onto different lines within python, or b) a better way to individually parse the information.

Here's what the text looks like within the files:

`"{\"time\":\"Fri Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019\", \"id\":720,\"text\":\"I'd really like to find a good solution to this problem.\",\"source\":\"href=\\\"http:\\/\\/stackoverflow.com\\\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1565376937344\"}\r\n""{\"time\":\"Sat Aug 10 22:16:00 +0000 2019\", \"id\":721,\"text\":\"And I would appreciate your help!\",\"source\":\"href=\\\"http:\\/\\/stackoverflow.com\\\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"156534564531\"}\r\n""{\"time\":\"Sun Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019\", \"id\":720,\"text\":\"Imagine additional text repeating below.\",\"source\":\"href=\\\"http:\\/\\/stackoverflow.com\\\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1565376937344\"}\r\n"`

If you assign the above text to a python object and ask python to print it, python returns what I want to see, i.e.:

`{"time":"Fri Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019", "id":720,"text":"I'd really like to find a good solution to this problem.","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1565376937344"}`

`{"time":"Sat Aug 10 22:16:00 +0000 2019", "id":721,"text":"And I would appreciate your help!","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"156534564531"}`

`{"time":"Sun Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019", "id":720,"text":"Imagine additional text repeating below.","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1565376937344"}`

But if I read the file to a python object and print that object, I get the original text. I’ve tried `f.read()`, `readline()`, `readlines()`, `splitlines()` (which gave me a riotous mess of additional \\s), and I’ve tried splitting the string using `splitstring()`. I’m very much at a loss, and I’ll admit that I’m fairly new to coding and have never really sat down to learn the basics.

Any help you can give me to take the above text and ultimately be able to translate them into individual JSON object and read, say, the texts from each would be great. My ultimate goal is to be able to call the dictionary keys from the individual json objects, like this:

```
for line in f:
    data = json.loads(line)
    print(data[‘text’])
```

and get the following list

```
"I'd really like to find a good solution to this problem."
"And I would appreciate your help!"
"Imagine additional text repeating below."
```

Comment: Can you please post (in a code block) a subset of the **exact** contents of your file? No repetitive quotes or anything.

Comment: @martineau it was more the multiline text using inline code ticks but in retrospect I can't think of a better way to do it since the OP pasted it as one line instead of several lnes.

Comment: Unfortunately, what's pasted above (the first code block) is exactly what's in my file, repetitive quotes and everything. Additionally unfortunately, the first block **is** one line, so I've pasted it in as is. Thank you for the formatting help.

Comment: @RachelSamuels Its in a single line of text? Not multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, it has quotes around the string, and it's all a single line of text when displayed in Notepad. I want to get it to multiple lines, preferably using the '\r\n' tags that are nested within the quotes.

Comment: Can you change the source of the data to output the data differently into the file?

Comment: I agree, the problem is whatever is generating the data isn't doing it properly. It looks like  the Python representation of a string and isn't valid JSON format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a large amount of data already in files like this, so I will ultimately have to be able to parse the data as it is in this format.

Comment: You may be able to use `ast.literal_eval()` to fix it.

Comment: How would that work/where would I begin to work on applying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem right, using [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) might do what you need:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('json_strings.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for line in literal_eval(line).splitlines():
            print(line)
```

Sample output:

```
{"time":"Fri Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019", "id":720,"text":"I'd really like to find a good solution to this problem.","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1565376937344"}
{"time":"Sat Aug 10 22:16:00 +0000 2019", "id":721,"text":"And I would appreciate your help!","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"156534564531"}
{"time":"Sun Aug 09 18:55:37 +0000 2019", "id":720,"text":"Imagine additional text repeating below.","source":"href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1565376937344"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I asked for. I have a clarification question, though. The output doesn't seem to have each segment separated from the others as new lines in the output. They're printing out on new lines, but I can't seem to iterate through each of them. Is there a way to go from here to have them as separate items in a list?

Comment: Wait, I think I got it--using splitlines(), I can get the individuals. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Rachel: That's good to hear and you're welcome. (I was updating my answer to do that when you figured it out yourself).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm running this code on the same data that you guys are, but when I execute this, I see that the type of `line` is `str`. Is it possible to turn that str into a dict? I don't see an obvious way to do so. For instance, `literal_eval(line)` gives me a SyntaxError, in particular complaining about the end of the "source" key-value pair, which seems to have been incorrectly escaped.

Comment: @Kevin: What we determined after a bit of back-and-forth in the comments is that the file contains _exactly_ what Rachel has in the question all on a single line. If you want to turn that into (three) dictionaries, you'll need to call `json.loads()` on each one of the lines `splitlines()` is generating. If you're the downvoter, I don't appreciate it.

Comment: Don't worry about me, I didn't downvote :-) After all, since I'm not sure I'm even using the right input data, the fault might be my own.

Comment: @Kevin: OK, no worries, I have no way of knowing one way or the other for sure. Hope the rest of my previous response clarified things a little.

Comment: @Kevin, I did exactly what @martineau said and used `splitlines()`, and then used `json.loads()` on each line of the resulting file. Just out of concern, though, what's the likeliest reason behind the 2 downvotes? I'd love to make my next question more clear/relevant, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Rachel: FWIW, I think your question's fine. Some drive-by random downvoter was in a bad mood and didn't even show the courtesy of leaving a comment.

Comment: @martineau: thank you for the kind words, and especially thank you for your answer! You saved me from a world of trouble. Have a wonderful day!